# How to encode an image to be inserted in a .jsp

Tags: image, jsp, binary, hex, oraclereports

I have a .jsp which I need to add an image in hex but the thing is that I don't know in which format the image has to be first in order to be recognized after it has been converted.

This is the code:

`<image name="B_1">`

`<geometryInfo x="0.50000" y="0.00000" width="1.43750" height="0.68750"/>`

`<advancedLayout printObjectOnPage="allPage"
         basePrintingOn="anchoringObject"/>`

`<visualSettings fillPattern="transparent" fillBackgroundColor="black"
         linePattern="transparent" lineBackgroundColor="black"/>`

`<points>`

```
<point x="0.00000" y="0.00000"/>
      <point x="1.43750" y="0.68750"/>
      <point x="0.50000" y="0.00000"/>
      <point x="1.43750" y="0.68750"/>
    </points>

<binaryData encoding="hexidecimal" dataId="image.B_1">
```

`here goes the encoded image (which format should it be?... .tif, .bmp, .jsp, .gif?`

`</binaryData>`

`</image>`

Anything will be helpful!

Thanks!

Comment: Is this an oracle report template?

Comment: Yes, it's an Oracle report template...

Comment: I've retagged to include oraclereports - I think that's pretty key